# Navigate to view controllers in NSObject type class

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

This is my code. It is an NSObject class and implementing Table View in this to show menus. By clicking on a table view cell I want to navigate to another view controller.

```
class SideMenuController: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let window: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        //print(indexPath.row)
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            //print("1 is")
            let storybord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            //let nextvc = storybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "manageprofilevcid") as! ManageProfileViewController
            let viewController = storybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "manageprofilevcid") as! ManageProfileViewController
            //let navi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            handleDismiss()
            //let ll = navigation
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to navigate to another view controller. Is there any code that will work in this NSObject class for perform navigation to specific view controller?

Comment: Check if your `navigationController` is `nil`.

Comment: Any reason `SideMenuController` is not inheriting from `UIViewController`. It seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Kamran NSObject and UIViewController both inheritance not working at a time. either use this or this

Comment: `UIViewController` is already `NSObject`. `UIViewController->UIResponder->NSObject`

Comment: Your ``SideMenuController`` is not actually controller but a plain ``NSObject. Do you inject an ``UINavigationController`` when initializing it?

Also, it would be great if you provide some more context to your questions in future. Does the method even get invoked? Some more of your code, stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

In your `NSObect` class of `SideMenuController` you have created a variable `navigationController` which you are using for `navigationController?.pushViewController`.

In the main controller you must have created the variable of `SideMenuController`.
In that add :

```
self.sideMenuController.navigationController = self.navigationController
```

and before using `navigationController?.pushViewController` check if `navigationController` is nil or not. you have to remove the `private` declaration to use `navigationController` variable in main view controller.

You haven't added the code of main view controller so I have answered according to the assumptions. Hope it helps.

You can also go with `Protocols` created in `SideMenuController` and write the code of segues or navigation in main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following points:

**1.** Inheriting from `NSObject` doesn't make any sense. `UIViewController` already does that.

```
class SideMenuController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

**2.** Check if you've set the tableView's delegate and dataSource.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

**3.** Where is code for instantiating `UINavigationController`? In case your `SideMenuController` is already embedded in a `navigationController`, there is no need to make a new instance.

Do clarify the use of `private weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?` here.